# Delphi cross-platform system utilities for system file functions

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I am migrating a Delphi 10.3 VCL application to Firemonkey. The units that do not use the GUI compile without any modification except for those which use the Windows-specific system functions mentioned below.

Can anyone point me to cross-platform system file utilities in Delphi/Firemonkey 10.3, or alternative workarounds, to carry out the following actions needed to complete my project:

- Extract the system icon for a file or application on the basis of its extension or MIME type
- Execute a system shell command, e.g. to open a file (equivalent to WinAPI `ShellExecute`)
- Launch an external program in a child process and wait for its termination (e.g. create a child process using WinAPI `CreateProcess` and wait using `WaitForSingleObject`)
- Get/set a file’s TimeCreated, TimeModified, & TimeAccessed timestamps so that a file copy may be made having the same timestamps as the source file.

I have Googled for these but the hits I have seen only refer to Windows functions. Some hits indicate that Free Pascal provides a `TProcess` class and `ExecuteProcess()`, `RunCommand()`, and `OpenDocument()` procedures that are described as being cross-platform.

Regarding the timestamps, it is possible to obtain these using the `FindFirst` and `FindNext` functions and then reading timestamps in the `TSearchRec` returned. But I didn't find how to set the timestamps in the FMX version, which I did in the VCL version using relevant Win API functions.

I am not asking for opinions or recommendations about the best out of a number of possible options, but for a factual answer to a specific question about Delphi 10.3's cross-platform support for basic system functions that one would expect to find in any mature GUI OS, such as Windows and Unix-based OS's. I searched for the an answer in the Delphi help system and on Google without success before posting the question on Stackoverflow. The first answer in this thread does just that. That I appreciate.

Comment: Which OS's do you want support for? Are you sure that all of these have this ability? Ie., Linux (and thus also MAC and Android) don't have a concept of "file type" based on extension (any file can be executable, no matter it's "extension"). Likewise, a "ShellExecute" may not be possible based only on a file name. Are you sure that all OS's have these three different time stamps for its files?

Comment: There is no universal set of functions for what you're asking, as not all OSes have that functionality available. Most of the functionality you've mentioned is Windows-specific and don't have equivalents on OSes like Android.

Comment: I don't know much about OS's other than Windows. However my understanding is that in the world of the internet, files do have a type, based on MIME type, which in turn is based on extension, so that email attachments and the like may be opened. I would have thought that all GUI OS's have  a command/API function to execute/open a file, which presumably gets called when the file icon is clicked or double-clicked. The executable file called may be a plug-in characterized as a class. Not all OS's may feature 3 file timestamps, but they presumably all have the DatetimeLastModified timestamp.

Comment: My main issue with cross platform apps is how to modify version numbers and details in a unified way

Comment: @Ken is right. Not everything you ask for is possible cross platform. Also, this is at least 4 different questions. And also off topic for being a recommendation question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The four points you are asking are too different for one single question in my view.

For your last point you find the solution in the unit `System.IOUtils.TFile`:

```
class function GetCreationTime(const Path: string): TDateTime; 
class procedure SetCreationTime(const Path: string; const CreationTime: TDateTime); 
class function GetLastAccessTime(const Path: string): TDateTime;
class procedure SetLastAccessTime(const Path: string; const LastAccessTime: TDateTime);
class function GetLastWriteTime(const Path: string): TDateTime;
class procedure SetLastWriteTime(const Path: string; const LastWriteTime: TDateTime);
```

For your point 1 to 3, there is yet no solution in Delphi's RTL.

For your point 2 and 3, I have implemented my own solution that is working for Windows and MacOS:

```
uses
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  WinApi.ShellApi; 
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  Posix.Stdlib;
  {$ENDIF}

class procedure TApiHelpers.OpenFileByOS(const FileName: string);
begin
  {$IFDEF MSWINDOWS}
  ShellExecute(0, 'open', PChar(FileName), nil, nil, SW_SHOW);
  {$ENDIF}
  {$IFDEF MACOS}
  _system(PAnsiChar(UTF8String('open "' + FileName + '"')));
  {$ENDIF}
end;
```

For a final solution, you have to check and handle the result of the API function `ShellExecute` and `System`.

For your first point, I have a solution working on windows only:

```
  function GetExtImg(const FileName: string; out ExtImg: IExtractImage): boolean;
  var
    Desktop, Target: IShellFolder;
    PIDL: PItemIDList;
    Attr, Eaten: DWORD;
    res: HResult;
  begin
    OleCheck(SHGetDesktopFolder(Desktop));
    OleCheck(Desktop.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PChar(ExcludeTrailingPathDelimiter(ExtractFilePath(FileName))), Eaten, PIDL, Attr));
    try
      OleCheck(Desktop.BindToObject(PIDL, nil, IShellFolder, Target));
    finally
      fMalloc.Free(PIDL);
    end;
    OleCheck(Target.ParseDisplayName(0, nil, PChar(ExtractFileName(FileName)), Eaten, PIDL, Attr));
    try
      Result := S_OK = Target.GetUIObjectOf(fOwnerForm[0], 1, PIDL, IExtractImage, nil, ExtImg);
    finally
      fMalloc.Free(PIDL);
    end;
  end;
```

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer which in my opinion adequately answers my question.